# How can I raise MouseClick Event on Sphere

Tags: c#, events, geometry, vtk

I am trying to raise an event in C# using VTK when I clicked in a sphere

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to implement a custom InteractorStyle. Inside it's OnLeftButtonDown(), you have to use a Picker, and then the ->GetActor() function of the picker will tell you which object you picked. If this object equals the object you were looking for, you now have the condition in which you have clicked your sphere and can do whatever you want.

(Here is a shell of this sort of situation (it doesn't check which object you clicked, but shows how to subclass the InteractorStyle and use the Picker): http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/Picking